# Upload picture on Google Assistant (Dialog Flow) Action doesn't work for IPhone XR or IPhone 11 when using a Basic Card

Tags: iphone, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

On IPhone XR or IPhone 11 (IOS 13.7), when we try uploading a picture using Google Action it doesn't work as expected and the app just closes and takes you to the App screen in the IPhone. This I believe would be broken for other actions that try to upload pictures.

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a simple Dialog Flow action with the following Basic Card returned by a webhook (Refer - https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#basic_card)

   ```
   conv.ask(new BasicCard({
   text: `This is a basic card. `, 
   subtitle: 'This is a subtitle',
   title: 'Title: this is a title',
   buttons: new Button({
   title: 'Upload Google Photo',
   url: 'https://photos.google.com/',
   }),
   image: new Image({
   url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
   alt: 'Image alternate text',
   }),
   display: 'CROPPED',
   }));
   ```
2. When the Basic Card shows up in the Google Assistant, Click on the "Upload Google Photo" button -> Upload icon -> Phone.
3. Ideally you should see the below options in the bottom of the screen allowing you to upload a picture
   `Take Photo or Video`, `Photo Library` and `Browse`
4. But instead Google Assistant closes and you are taken to App screen in IPhone

It doesn't work on IPhone XR & IPhone 11 & possibly the newer IPhones

It works as expected on IPhone 6 (IOS 12.4) and IPad ( running on IOS 13.7) and Android phones & tablets so I feel the issue is specific to the newer IPhones . Attaching the picture of what is expected (seeing options to upload picture from IPhone ). Same behavior is observed for any site that has Upload picture/ File - For example in the basic Card replace https://photos.google.com/ with "https://imgbb.com/"

The same link works as expected on IPhone 11 or XR when use directed on the Safari or Chrome browser, the issue seems specific to Google Assistant opening a website within it

[Screenshot of IPhone Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgoS3.jpg)

Comment: Is this the same behavior for *any* link? Or just those that have an image upload feature on the targeted page?

Comment: It is only for any link that has an image upload on the page which tries to access IPhone's storage (even though Google Assistant has access been given access to Camera & Photos)

Comment: Does this happen in other webviews from other apps? It could be related to a webview bug.